# get day of week from returned date from server

Tags: javascript

I'm retrieving a timestamp from a server as follows:

```
2016-03-08 15:30
```

I have an array to pass in to get the day of the week:

```
var dayNameArray = {
"0": "Sun",
"1": "Mon",
"2": "Tue",
"3": "Wed",
"4": "Thu",
"5": "Fri",
"6": "Sat"
}
```

How would I get this to say what the day of the week is? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Construct Date from string and use [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method to get day number:

```
var myDate = new Date("2016-03-08 15:30");
var dayNum = myDate.getDay();

var dayNameArray = {
  "0": "Sun",
  "1": "Mon",
  "2": "Tue",
  "3": "Wed",
  "4": "Thu",
  "5": "Fri",
  "6": "Sat"
}
console.log(dayNameArray[dayNum]);
```

Comment: Oh wow so I tried constructing a new Date object just like you did, but did it differently and it didn't turn out right...but your way is the right way to do it!

Comment: @KodyR. nice that answer works for you, cool :D Have a nice day )

Answer (score 2):

A short version:

```js
var date = new Date('2016-03-08 15:30'.replace(/\-/g, '/'));
var day = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'.split(' ')[date.getDay()];

console.log(day);
```

The current construction uses the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, which is shorter than the regular array:

```
'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'.split(' ')
['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
```

My suggestion is to replace all `-` with `/` for compatibility with more browsers. For more details please see ["Why `new Date()` is always return `null`?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583164/why-new-date-is-always-return-null) question and answers.