# Why New Date() is always return null?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, format

If a date format is `$scope.timestamp =  '2016-12-16 07:02:15 am'`

I want to format to `16/12/2016 07:02:15 am`

I have tried this below code and it's working good

```
$scope.originalStamp = $filter('date')
                          (new Date($scope.timestamp.replace("-","/")),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a');
```

> But my question is why `new Date($scope.timestamp)` is always return `null` if am not use replace the char from (-) to (/)?

see the below code is not working if am without using `replace().`

```
$scope.originalStamp = $filter('date')
                              (new Date($scope.timestamp),'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a');
```

> Why the `new Date()` does not accept if the date format having (-)? Is new Date() conversion is depend by my system date format?

Comment: You should not use the Date constructor to parse strings at all. Write a small function or use a library. It should not be returning *null* but an invalid Date (i.e. a Date object with time value of NaN) that might be interpreted later as *null*.

Comment: Did you try 01-01-2016?

Comment: `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a'`, not `'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a'`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna—did you read the OP?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Yes.

Comment: @RobG But that is works well if I pass the value is `'2016/12/16 07:02:15 am'`. ? Why?

Comment: >Why the new Date() does not accept if the date format having (-)? Is new Date() conversion is depend by my system date format?

Comment: @RameshRajendran—see my answer.

Comment: @RameshRajendran—in implementation may decide that "2016/12/16" is an invalid attempt at an ISO 8601 date string and return *NaN*, or it might decided that it's not ISO 8601 and fall back to whatever heuristics it wants, perhaps returning a date for 16 December, 2016. Both behaviours are consistent with ECMA-262.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the new Date() does not accept if the date format having (-)?

Parsing of date strings other than the limited subset of [ISO 8601 included in ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) is implementation dependent. You may get the correct result, an incorrect result or an invalid date. Therefore it is strongly recommended not to use the *Date* constructor or *Date.parse* to parse strings (they are equivalent for parsing), always manually parse strings with a library or bespoke function.

> Is new Date() conversion is depend by my system date format?

No. There are a number of formats that are supported by convention (see [*MDN Date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)), however you should not rely on that as some are parsed, or parsed differently, in some browsers but not others.

You might try one of these libraries:

1. [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com): parsing, formatting, arithmetic, manipulation
2. [Fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha): just parsing and formatting

PS

If you just want to reformat '2016-12-16 07:02:15 am' as '16/12/2016 07:02:15 am', then:

```js
// Reformat a date like '2016-12-16 07:02:15 am' as
// '16/12/2016 07:02:15 am'
function reformatDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/[ -]/);
  return [b[2],b[1],b[0]].join('/') + ' ' + b[3] + ' ' + b[4];
}
 
var s = '2016-12-16 07:02:15 am';
console.log(s + ' => ' + reformatDate(s))
```

Comment: Very well. +1. And Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. new Date(2013, 13, 1) is equivalent to new Date(2014, 1, 1), both create a date for 2014-02-01 (note that the month is 0-based). Similarly for other values: new Date(2013, 2, 1, 0, 70) is equivalent to new Date(2013, 2, 1, 1, 10) which both create a date for 2013-03-01T01:10:00.

Comment: @RameshRajendran—yes, but that is a **very** useful feature. ;-)